# How to check if there is text within my JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I want to check whether there is something in my JButton. What would i insert into the `equalsIgnoreCase()` area?

```
if (jButton1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("") &&
    jButton2.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("") &&
    jButton3.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("") &&
    jButton4.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("") &&
    jButton5.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("") &&
    jButton6.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("") &&
    jButton7.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("") &&
    jButton8.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("") &&
    jButton9.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
jButton1.getText().isEmpty()
```

(use ! to negate if you want to know it's not empty...)

or you can check the length of the value

```
jButton1.getText().length > 0
```

Comment: Ok. Use !jButton1.getText().isEmpty() to say "If NOT empty"

Answer (score 1):

To check that there is a text, you can do:

```
!jButton1.getText().isEmpty()
```

or, if you want to exclude a text that only contains spaces:

```
!jButton1.getText().trim().isEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
bool somethingIn = !jButton1.getText().isEmpty();
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, just what you did. But you should put exclamation symbols before conditions to negate them:

```
if (!jButton1.getText().equals("") &&
    !jButton2.getText().equals("") &&
    !jButton3.getText().equals("") &&
    !jButton4.getText().equals("") &&
    !jButton5.getText().equals("") &&
    !jButton6.getText().equals("") &&
    !jButton7.getText().equals("") &&
    !jButton8.getText().equals("") &&
    !jButton9.getText().equals(""))
```

In this case body of if will be executed if all your JButtons have some text. And ignoreCase is not necessary. Emptiness has no lower or upper case ))